# Splitting up a DataSet based on a filter

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have the first column in my DataSet populated with numbers 1-4. I would like to be able to filter and split my DataSet into four different DataSets based on the number inside.

So for example if I have:

```
Dim ds as New DataSet
```

I would like to split ds into four different DataSets (while maintaining the original ds). In order to achieve this:

```
 Dim ds1 as New DataSet 'contains all rows that have the number 1 in the first column
 Dim ds2 as New DataSet 'contains all rows that have the number 2 in the first column
 Dim ds3 as New DataSet 'contains all rows that have the number 3 in the first column
 Dim ds4 as New DataSet 'contains all rows that have the number 4 in the first column
```

There are about 1,000 rows in total, so this needs to be done preferably in the most efficient and quickest manner possible. Can anyone help please?

As per Plutonix's suggestion:

```
Dim newDV As New DataView
newDV = ds.Tables("Table1").DefaultView
newDV.RowFilter = "COLUMNONENAME = 2"
```

When I put this into a try/catch, it catches an error, but when it's not in a try/catch, no error. Weird.
So now I try to display the info:

```
txtBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(newDV(0)("COLUMNONENAME"))
```

This should display the first entry that has the number 2 in COLUMNONENAME, but instead it still displays the first entry of DataSet regardless of what the entry in COLUMNONENAME is.

Comment: An actual filter would only show/give you access to those rows, you dont need to "split them up", just use some DataViews (which also allows you to hold onto the original DT).  And you certainly dont need 4 datasets - DataSets do not hold data but rather the DataTables which hold the rows.

Comment: @Plutonix Would that be something like this?             dv = New DataView(DataSet.Tables("Table 1"), "1", "COLUMN 1", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows) to get every row with the number 1 in column 1?

Comment: I typically build the DV and then set the filter `newDV.RowFilter = "Color = ;Red'"`

Comment: @Plutonix So like this?             dv = DataSet.Tables("Table1").DefaultView     and then             dv.RowFilter = "STATUS = ;1"How does it know to search through column 1 only?

Comment: Did you read the last comment?  `dvUrgent.RowFilter = "ColumnOneName = 1"`   that should read `newDV.RowFilter = "Color = 'Red'"` ...fat fingers

Comment: @Plutonix Hey...sorry - I updated the original post. Can you take a look please?

Comment: Thats not how you proposed to build it in comments.. `Dim dvA = New DataView(ds.Tables(0))`  If you are getting an error you need to tell us what that error is to get help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160316/discussion-between-lolikols-and-plutonix).